# Equivalent of background service for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, socket.io, background-service

I am currently porting an Android app to iOS but i can't seem to find a good equivalent for background service of Android to handle user requests.
The Android app has a background service with an Socket.IO object and with sending BroadcastReceivers back and forth between UI and service i can handle requests as well (By replacing BroadcastReceivers with EventBus i could update UI with changes that were done during the time app was in background). Before iOS 10 voip calls was recommended for users for such tasks but then it was deprecated and pushKit came instead but it doesn't let app know about push notification. Anyway i am looking for a good architecture to give me these features if anyone has an opinion i would be more than happy to hear it.

- It should be able to hold a single Socket object and keep it alive
  and accessible to UI elements in background without blocking UI.
- Some socket events need to have Notification if the app is in
  background if it's in the foreground then request UI to make some
  changes. (If it could update UI in background when app is in background and present user with updated UI too that would be better)
- Sending events between Socket object and UI to needs be easy and
  decoupled as possible because there are lots of events with different
  properties.

Comment: iOS has limited background modes. You can keep a socket connected to a server when your app is in the foreground but if your app is in the background you should use either silent push notifications or PushKit notifications if your app is a VoIP app.  I don't know why you say that PushKit doesn't let the app know about push notifications; that is precisely what it does

Comment: My app is a transportation app like uber, but how can i know about a server event when app is in background and socket is being disconnected? Also when app is in foreground how can i wire requests between UI and socket object?

Comment: Typically you would use push notifications to notify your app when it is in the background. In the foreground you just write code. You could use a delegate pattern or `NSNotification`.

Comment: On foreground mode how to make Socket object and events accessible to all classes inside app? Can singleton classes do such thing? how to make it work in background and don't block UI thread?

Comment: You could use a singleton. Networking libraries such as Alamofire and NSURLConnection support delegation and asynchronous callbacks so you won't block the main thread.